# java prevent header, cookie injection?

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8

Today while working I came to know a weird issue which I never faced what happened one my client added query params in one of my post request and it gets added in response header and in my filter I am not adding that to header it automatically getting added
:

```
http://localhost:9898/app/rest/data/fetch
```

this is my Post request but when user added query params to it:

```
http://localhost:9898/app/rest/data/fetch?Location=https://www.google.com/
```

this gets added in response header:

```
accept →*/*
accept-encoding →gzip, deflate, br
accept-language →en-US,en;q=0.9
auth-token →eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkExMjhDQkMtSFMyNTYiLCJjdHkiOiJqd3QifQ.dFChYC8aWe7E0Dvsvy7cRRKlQnNqH3Yzdgkoaa3Eq3tuc-w4fGryP_H01dgx_PbNnXcGGZoiuZ73hB60RYTWC8A2zKB-hULWY09uVkaQcNrXlFIHg0Rf5nfa91uK-peABNe5Tsp7oEjZcrgGVYAZx5B3DzU9SKxLwai6QTf9zNHapIP043hBgxJWl5Pn-851K1I37SNp7pW5WolGDGH2xN6jUpc4L0QM759RbfIBw2uGVuZbR6v5OQ7ePbD3pj06mSL6XZkN0Dyiahfat0tse3SrAs73j_l6yXuQeyy0goypbtAANSg2O4R-1m_-0Hwq4Ew2zbwkSOJXnpWOc9HFSg.p4k4CsxQN2G_I_pCMbQiWg.BvbSir5Z2bY2T8Pgu1EOFN1Cbq4TEBRmotVzW9LsEhDCnZIgvI0elUu8gC2p0n2rldJ_01jKM4s2jcQwTW43enRqXJjilMBXctErB3Mv2uqwe4bRM92IlPpLNqJOHwna0lNOPzQeXA9lqTWgEpo8lGA2sPqRrl3oIS68OjmsDSc5T6PdXmcKq1n-j2214h8GogMVutNKSeZ7S3NmSD59ygeWZwAKqsSf8HDzJS7UqaXUDuDk1YW3EEco4OdKDlm4UBVys0JSRotSvbFl-FowvuCurNIJZoOuJY9DE7-cZdNMrKKZ8zAhp64V8CeSAJmIXetxyEoVCw9-K745XTPm9pzf3Jt1v3Cic0h92E3zFNzh9_Co8dQEw2CAhifKcnx1QXcG30X306iixK0lSJblKrQzRTTmSjtADu9C_KDqrO4y04edxcI6ARCDsHCF3GiiAxlkuueIqeXiLzonwBZrvSxcRrv2c4xiVkJQ7wimNJ58biuiWJ4p-59oCt3a-h8EsfMrlnJk7M_J0xIKNZdXE4QjuN-iR8rTr-IffF2XcSycTtALJB1AFOU7ZCNRYSenjHaE02_Hxu4xYfJ2HKoyTy30eQj8EhnlkZgYPPJ4MHKACTZboJBwdRV6uaxyrMc2uA7CNP3wSDCGnEBeVL2qXpebqF3uplTj_y0ZtQsH6eBTx4Pbh8-b7MfkQxlwtlpfICACf7C4qkYyF9dNUwHs6Q.Y7ZgeEyxZz86xAddlgH1mQ
breadcrumbid →ID-LAPTOP-3KEFOF60-60042-1635422818548-0-50
**Location →https://www.google.com/**
```

How can we avoid this as if user add something else it's get added to the headers:

http://localhost:9898/app/rest/data/fetch?SET-COOKIE=fdgfdgfdgdg

etc.
I am simply allowing request:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;

 }
```

Please help how can we prevent this kind of injections?

Comment: I'm not aware of any default behavior that randomly adds GET parameters to the response header.

Comment: I am also not I am using apache camel for rest request and it is doing